# Java - Is it acceptable to synchronize threads on a ConcurrentSkipListMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentskiplistmap

I have a program where many threads post their requests to a `PriorityQueue`.
Later, they wait for a response from `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. There is ONE thread that publishes answers to the `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

The following lines of code illustrate this :

**At program init**

```
PriorityQueue<Request> requests = new PriorityQueue<Request>();
ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, Reponse> responsesReceived = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, Reponse>();
```

**In a caller thread**

```
// Send request ...
Request r = ... // Elaborate the request 
requests.add(r);

// ... then wait for an answer
Long id = r.getId();
while (responsesReceived.containsKey(id) == false) {
    synchronized (responsesReceived) {
         responsesReceived.wait();
    }
}

Answer a = responsesReceived.take(id);

// Do other things ...
```

**In THE response handler thread**

```
// Wait for a remote answer
Answer answer = ...;

// Once received publish it in ConcurrentSkipListMap
responsesReceived.put(answer.getRequestId(), answer);

synchronized (responsesReceived) {
    responsesReceived.notify();
}

// Go back and wait for a new answer...
```

**QUESTION**

- Is it safe to synchronize caller threads and response handler thread on the `ConcurrentSkipListMap` ?
- Should I rather use a Lock for the synchronization ?
- Should I use a `HashMap` of locks (`HashMap<Long,Object>`) ?

I'm pretty new with the java.util.concurrent API and I have some doubts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this can work, it may not be the clearest way to represent what you are doing.  I would add a separate "lock" object for such notifications.

Note: I would use notifyAll() unless you only ever have one waiting thread.

Answer (score 1):

With synchronized/wait/notify, you can use any object as lock. As for submitting jobs to a queue and waiting for their results, take a look at `ExcutorService`, `Future`, and `CompletionService`.

Comment: +1 As using an ExecutorService is likely to be a better solution.